# Chrome extension - changing the popup icon onClick / onHover

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find a way to change the extension's icon once the  popup is either open or hovered.
I found a way to do it when opening the popup, using:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
```

but,couldn't find a way to catch the popup close event. i tried to use this from the popup code:

```
 var port = chrome.runtime.connect();
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(function()
  {
     alert('closed');
  });
```

But was unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the popup page is connecting to a background script, try moving the Port.onDisconnect code to the background script:

```
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(function()
  {
     alert('closed');
  });
```

I'm assuming that your way wasn't working because after you close the popup, it's dead and cannot detect the Port.onDisconnect event. If you move that to your background script, it should still be alive, would be notified when the Port was disconnected, and could change the button's icon itself!

As for changing the icon when the extension is hovered, it would depend on if you mean to do it when the button on the toolbar is hovered or to do it when the popup page is hovered. If you mean the former, I do not think this is possible. If you mean the latter, the popup page should be able to do it through an event listener and your "updateIcon" function.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah!
Assuming i move the port.onDisconnect to the backgrond.js, how do i get access to the port object?

And for the hover issue, i meant the first options (when the popup is close)...

Comment: @Meytaln You would need to add a [chrome.runtime.onConnect](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onConnect) listener to your background page and grab the Port from that. And given your criteria, I am not aware of any way that you could detect when the user hovers over your extension's icon. Good luck!